# Get first and last records in a group in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a set of Gps points ordered by Id1 and Id2. For each group, I have to get the first and last records as shown in the output.

I tried partitioning it based on Id1 and Id2 and get then ordered it based on STime in both asc and desc order and get their first and last records, but i dont get the desired results. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    Id1 Id2 STime                 ETime                 Latitude    Longitude
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41   2016-11-23 12:17:20   26.1258755  -80.1347351      
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41     2016-11-23 12:17:20     26.1258755  -80.1347351      
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41     2016-11-23 12:17:20     26.1258488  -80.13432    
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41     2016-11-23 12:17:20     26.1261063  -80.13432    
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41     2016-11-23 12:17:20     26.1261559  -80.13432
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.12608    -80.13691    
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.12608    -80.13691    
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.1261559  -80.13696    
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.1261559  -80.13696    
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.1261063  -80.13696


    Id1 Id2 STime                 ETime                 Latitude    Longitude
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41   2016-11-23 12:17:20   26.1258755  -80.1347351      
    11  112 2016-11-23 12:15:41     2016-11-23 12:17:20     26.1261559  -80.13432
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.12608    -80.13691    
    11  113 2016-11-23 12:24:13     2016-11-23 12:48:16     26.1261063  -80.13696
```

Current query:

```
    SELECT
      A.Id1 ,
      A.Id2,
      STime,
      ETime,
      Latitude,
      Longitude
    FROM
      M.A AS A
    JOIN
      L.B AS B
    ON
      A.STime < B.DateTime
      AND A.ETime >= B.DateTime
      AND A.ID1 = B.Id1
    WHERE
      (A._PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-11-23')
        AND TIMESTAMP('2016-11-23')
        AND A.Id1 IN (550315976))
    ORDER BY
      B.Id1,
      A.Id1,
    B.DateTime
```

Comment: It might help to clarify what defines a group. In your query, you are joining only on `Id1`, not `Id2`, so `A` and `B` end up with the same `Id1` values but potentially different `Id2` values.

Comment: Read the best practices of asking : How to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  To be specific, I would suggest you to add `examples of both tables` and clarify `meaning of first and last record`